Pytube program gives neither output nor error
I've been running a pytube program to download a playlist audio, but unfortunately its behavior is incomprehensible. After I run it, the program takes too long time to do such a simple task, and it doesn't result in an error, just nothing, the running is endless. It seems to me that it behaves as though it expects a user to give an input, but there's nothing like that in the code.
import re
from pytube import Playlist


YOUTUBE_STREAM_AUDIO = 140  # modify the value to download a different stream
DOWNLOAD_DIR = r'C:\Users\spane\Downloads'

playlist = Playlist('https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLZHQObOWTQDNU6R1_67000Dx_ZCJB-3pi')


# this fixes the empty playlist.videos list
playlist._video_regex = re.compile(r"\"url\":\"(/watch\?v=[\w-]*)")


# physically downloading the audio track
for video in playlist.videos:
    audioStream = video.streams.get_by_itag(YOUTUBE_STREAM_AUDIO)
    audioStream.download(output_path=DOWNLOAD_DIR)
    print('Done! ')


Cannot reproduce. Your code gives me urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request

It seems to be a known pytube bug. Use pytubefix as a temporary fix.
Just pip install pytubefix and change from pytube import Playlist to:
from pytubefix import Playlist

EDIT:
I get Bad Request error when I run this code

thanks for your answer, but this still doesn't work( I even haven't got Bad Request, because it is still running
